# Question on the Rankin-Selberg epsilon function

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $\pi$ and $\pi'$ be unitary cuspidal automorphic representation of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{A})$ and  $\mathrm{GL}_m(\mathbb{A})$, respectively.

It is well known that the complete Rankin-Selberg $L$-function $L(s,\pi \otimes \pi')$ has possible poles only at $s=0,1$ and has no zeros on $\mathrm{Re}(s) \ge 1$.

I am wondering whether there are theorems for complete Rankin-Selberg epsilon factor $\epsilon(s,\pi \otimes \pi')$ which concerns the zeros or poles of it.

Comment: It's entire and nonvanishing. It's of the form $\epsilon_{\pi} q^{-(s - 1/2)}$ for some positive integer $q$ (the arithmetic conductor of $\pi \otimes \pi'$) and some constant $\epsilon_{\pi}$ of absolute value $1$. This result is probably either contained in Jacquet-Piatetski-Shapiro-Shalika's paper on Rankin-Selberg convolutions or any of Cogdell's surveys on $L$-functions associated to automorphic representations.

Comment: @PeterHumphries, Fantastic! Thank you for your kind answer. I will look the references you recommended!